# Images appearing as broken images in Django project

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm getting a broken image in a django project, but as far as I have checked, the code looks right.
Here's the code in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have also imported the media option in the templates section:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Here's the code I'm using in the template.

```
{% if request.user.profile.picture %}
<img src="{{ request.user.profile.picture.url }}" height="35" class="d-inline-block align-top rounded-circle">
{% else %}
<img src="{% static 'img/default-profile.png' %}" height="35" class="d-inline-block align-top rounded-circle">
{% endif %}
```

The default-profile.png image is loading correctly, but the other profile pictures are not, although they have been loading correctly to the media folder and their urls are displayed correctly in the database. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

The HTML output of the image is the following:

```
<img src="/media/users/pictures/Foto.jpg" height="35" class="d-inline-block align-top rounded-circle">
```

It looks correct when checking the src tag, as it matches the MEDIA_URL with the valur that was stored in the database after it.

Comment: if you try to access the image resource in the browser using the full path <domain>/media.......jpg what happens?

Comment: @t.stv Error 404.

Comment: so your image is not on the server. can you access anything in the media folder?

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be happening is that you're not serving the media files correctly during development. You can try appending this to the `urlpatterns` list on your site's **urls.py** file.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Please refer to [this information in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) for more details.